# how to segue to 2nd page from successful login - "warning attempt to present on while a presentation is in progress" error

Tags: swift, authentication

How do I segue to my 2nd page after successfully verifying login?

I have pulled a segue from the login page view controller (not the login button) to the next page and named the segue 'nextPage'. (If I segue from the login button then the button click allows all logins to segue through without testing them). When I segue from the login page it correctly checks details but does not segue to the next page on successful login, and instead I get the console error "Warning: Attempt to present  on  while a presentation is in progress!"

the code is

```
   @IBAction func loginButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

       let userEmail = userEmailTextField.text;
    let userPassword = userPasswordTextField.text;
    let userEmailStored = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("userEmail");
    let userPasswordStored = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("userPassword");
    if userEmailStored == userEmail && userPasswordStored == userPassword {
        // Login successful
        // Display an alert message
        displayMyAlertMessage("Login successful. Thank you");
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true,forKey:"isUserLoggedIn");
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize();
        print("login success!")
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion:nil);
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("nextPage", sender: self);


    } else if userEmailStored != userEmail {
        // Login unsuccessful (email incorrect)
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(false,forKey:"isUserLoggedIn");
        print("login unsuccessful. Incorrect email.")
        // Display an alert message
        displayMyAlertMessage("Incorrect login details.");
        return;
    } else if userPasswordStored != userPassword {
        // Login unsuccessful (password incorrect)
        // Display an alert message
        displayMyAlertMessage("Incorrect login details");
        //return;
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(false,forKey:"isUserLoggedIn");
        print("login unsuccessful. Incorrect password.")


    }
```

The login page comes after an initial 'protected' login/logout screen as ViewController.swift with this code

```
     override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool)
{

    let isUserLoggedIn = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("isUserLoggedIn");


    if(!isUserLoggedIn)
    {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("loginView", sender: self);
    }


}


@IBAction func logoutButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(false,forKey:"isUserLoggedIn");
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize();

    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("loginView", sender: self);


}
```

}

[image: storyboard sequence]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by removing the alert controller function, i.e. the code

displayMyAlertMessage("Login successful. Thank you");

as this was segueing to the 'login successful' popup view controller, instead of the segue that I needed, and in effect blocking the next page, while also not really necessary, as successful login means moving to the next page. I was able to still keep the alert/ popups for 'incorrect login details' which were the only essential alerts.

Answer (score 1):

I do suggest to have a different approach on this.

If you set a `storyboardID` to `LoginViewController` you can directly manage to override the Protected page checking directly in `AppDelegate`.

For example you can try to do this

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
[...]

    let isUserLoggedIn = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("isUserLoggedIn")

if isUserLoggedIn  {

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("IDYOUSETBEFORE")

        window.rootViewController = vc
        return
}
```

I recently managed to release a pod in order to easily handle this situations, have a look at [StoryboardEnum lib](https://github.com/matteocrippa/StoryboardEnum)

Comment: thanks @gh3, I will try this out, (and your storyboardEnum lib too - sounds great!)

Comment: this is great, but that is only good for users who are currently logged in. if they have to go to the login page i cannot access the window